# This site needs more pictures!

Tags: discussion

Browsing *The Great Outdoors* is *dull*, *dull*, *dull*. The site is devoid of any colour and is reminiscent of monochrome bulletin boards from before I was even born — which is more than a quarter of a century ago. As long as we're in beta the layout is doomed to remain dull, but let's at least spice up questions and answers with some pictures!

[image: View from Rundtinden, Vågan, Lofoten, Norway, 13 October 2012]
View from Rundtinden, Vågan, Lofoten, Norway, 13 October 2012

Now the photograph above doesn't add *anything* to the post. Of course, in general photos should add something to the topic. But *let's add pictures whenever appropriate* so that browsing the site becomes a more enjoyable experience!

Answer (score 12):

Pictures, for pictures sake: No!

Pictures, where they add value to the answer: Yes, absolutely!

A picture, as they say, tells a thousand words.  But an inappropriate picture is just as inappropriate as those thousand words.

Answer (score 6):

I agree about adding pictures when appropriate, and there are multiple questions and answers on here (including some of mine) that would do well to have some. However, we should just as much, if not more so guard against needless images or diagrams, since they break up a post and provide a more fragmented experience without adding anything.

Comment: I agree; sometimes it is better to provide a link to the picture.

Answer (score 5):

Photos are very good when they **illustrate a point** of the question, and they provide some additional information to it. The same applies to answer.

I see the great value in the panorama-photos of beautiful landscapes, which should attract visitors to the site. They are great applicable to the questions about trails, camping, mountains etc.

However, there are some questions when I can hardly find any possible photo to illustrate them:

- [Is cold shock response a real danger, if someone is used to cold water?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/is-cold-shock-response-a-real-danger-if-someone-is-used-to-cold-water) - a photo of naked Bear Grylls jumping into half-frozen river?
- [Chasing with mosquitoes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/chasing-with-mosquitoes) - no idea, really
- [How many calories (aprox.) do we lose when washing in (very) cold water?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/how-many-calories-aprox-do-we-lose-when-washing-in-very-cold-water) - I have some idea, but I won't post it!
- [What do you risk when you ignore blisters and carry on walking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/what-do-you-risk-when-you-ignore-blisters-and-carry-on-walking) - oh, there's a good possible photo, but I'm afraid it would be quite disgusting